# Why would using a nosql/document/MongoDB as a relational database be inferior?

Tags: mongodb, rdbms, nosql

I have recently been introduced to MongoDB and I've come to like a lot (compared to MySQL i used for all projects).

However in some certain situations, storing my data with documents "linking" to each other with simple IDs makes more sense (to reduce duplicated data).

For example, I may have `Country` and `User` documents, where a user's location is actually an ID to a `Country` (since a `Country` document includes more data, hence duplicating `Country` data in each user makes no sense).

What I am curious about is.. why would MongoDB be inferior compared to using a *proper* relationship database?

Is it because I can save transactions by doing joins (as opposed to doing two transactions with MongoDB)?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a good question..!!

I would say there is definitely nothing wrong in using nosql db for the type of data you have described. For simple usecases it will work perfectly well.

The only point is that relational databases have been designed long time back to serve the purpose of storing and querying WELL STRUCTURED DATA.. with proper relations defined. Hence for a large amount of well structured data the performance and the features provided will be a lot more than that provided by a nosql database. Since they are more matured.. its their ball game..!!

On the other hand nosql databases have been designed to handle very large amount of unstructured data and has out of the box support for distributed environment scaling. So its a completely different ball game now..

They basically treat data differently and hence have different strategies / execution plans to fetch a given data..

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB was designed from the ground up to be scalable over multiple servers. When a MongoDB database gets too slow or too big for a single server, you can add additional servers by making the larger collections "sharded". That means that the collection is divided between different servers and each one is responsible for managing a different part of the collection.

The reason why MongoDB doesn't do JOINs is that it is impossible to have JOINs perform well when one or both collections are sharded over multiple nodes. A JOIN requires to compare each entry of table/collection A with each one of table/collection B. There are shortcuts for this when all the data is on one server. But when the data is distributed over multiple servers, large amounts of data need to be compared and synchronized between them. This would require a lot of network traffic and make the operation very slow and expensive.

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question, the reasons why MongoDB would be inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that you have only two tables, country and user. If so, it seems to me the only data duplicated is a foreign key, which is not a big deal. If there is more duplicated, then I question the DB design itself.

In concept, you can do it in NOSQL but why? Just because NOSQL is new? OK, then do it to learn but remember, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." Apparently the application is already running on relational. If the data is stored in separate documents in MongoDB and you want to interrelate them, you will need to use a link, which will be more work than a join and be slower. You will have to store a link, which would be no better than storing the foreign key. Alternatively, you can embed one document in another in MongoDB, which might even increase duplication.

If it is currently running on MySQL then it is not running on distributed servers, so Mongo's use of distributed servers is irrelevant. You would have to add servers to take advantage of that. If the tables are properly indexed in relational, it will not have to search through large amounts of data.

However, this is not a complex application and you can use either. If the data is stored on an MPP environment with relational, it will run very well and will not need to search to large amounts of data at all. There are two requirements, however, in choosing a partitioning key in MPP: 1. pick one that will achieve an even distribution of data; and 2. pick a key that can allow collocation of data. I recommend you use the same key as the partitioning key (shard key) in both files.

As much as I love MongoDB, I don't see the value in moving your app.